# Rotating a yoga pro 2 screen with xrandr on ubuntu 15.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, screen, xrandr, yoga-2

I just upgraded to ubuntu 15.04 and the xrandr command I used to use has stopped working:

```
xrandr --output eDP1 --rotate inverted
```

All the other rotations work fine, "left, right, normal."

But inverted causes the screen to go blank.  Anyone else in the same boat?  Anyone with a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been answered here

[Problem with xrandr rotation inverted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/626221/problem-with-xrandr-rotation-inverted/631283#631283)

Hope it will work for you

Comment: If it need same answer then most probably it's a duplicate question. Better to move it as comment.

Comment: @Sneetsher I cannot comment because I'm a new user...

Comment: OK, You can leave it, but if you get accepted in any one of them flag the other as duplicate. BTW Welcome to Ask Ubuntu :) I forgot that. Good luck.